# asp:LinqDataSource DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable that I fill manually, ie,

```
newrow = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(newrow);
```

and Im trying to benefit from the `groupby` features of `LinqDataSource` ([as shown by Matt](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html)) by linking the `LinqDataSource` to the `DataTable`, but its just not happening.

Has anyone any experience with this?

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    public class MyData
    {
        public MyData(){}

        private DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
        public DataTable MyTable
        {
            get { return dt; }
            set { dt = value; }
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyData mydata = new MyData();
        mydata.MyTable.Columns.Add("column1");
        DataRow dr = mydata.MyTable.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "some data";
        mydata.MyTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:LinqDataSource 
            ID="LinqDataSource1" 
            runat="server"
            ContextTypeName="MyData" 
            TableName="MyTable">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific that "its just not happening".  Please post your code and explain what isn't working.

Comment: The code is so simple that anyone with experience would have picked up on it :)  but never the less, I will add some code

Comment: I have a lot of experience but I am unable to diagnose problems with none extent code with a description of "its just not happening"  for all i know you code says `var arse = "feck"`;

Answer (score 1):

"dt" is not the name of the table try this

`DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");`

and then try this would name the table as "dt".

Comment: Thanks Nikshep but what would i put for the ContextTypeName

Answer (score 1):

No that just won't work at all.  The `ContextTypeName` property needs to be that of a  Context like a LinqtoSql DataContext and the `TableName` is the name of the database table that is mapped in your LinqToSql DBML file.  Have you tried actually following the article you link to as it gives a pretty good overview of getting LinqToSQL going.

Comment: but i am not trying to linq to a database

Comment: It doesn't have to be a database.  The DataContextType needs to be some kind of class that contains your data and then TableName needs to be some kind of property that returns a collection. See the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.contexttypename.aspx

Comment: Ive tried to use a class and a datatable within that class but it doesnt work either. (I edited my question to show the new code)

Comment: Because you have put it in the ASPX page that class exists inside of your Page class you may need to refer to it as PageName.MyClass.  Generally can you be much more specific.  "It doesn't work" is not very helpfull, please describe what is heppening, are you getting exception or error messages etc.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'MyData'.

Comment: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type '__test_linqdatasource_aspx.MyData'.

Comment: Ok! It works if I take it out of the page and put it in its own class.cs and I get all the details of that table displayed in the GridView

CaseSensitive IsInitialized DisplayExpression HasErrors MinimumCapacity TableName Namespace Prefix DesignMode

Comment: But it still wont work with calling the class from within the same page showing the Exception Details above... :(

Comment: In general, is it possible to bind a DataTable to a LinqDataSource? Can I access it's columns like fields? I tried a little bit but it gave the exception "the page or property xy could not be found in the datasource"... It that the same topic or should I open a new question?